# What is the advantage of binding to a socket instead of an IP?

Tags: python, nginx, gunicorn

I'm following [this guide](https://kevalnagda.github.io/flask-app-with-wsgi-and-nginx) to deploy a flask application to production using gunicorn

I get to this line `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app` and it works perfectly
After that the author recommends this instead `gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/movieapp/app.sock -m 777 wsgi:app`

So my question: what is the advantage of binding to a socket instead of an IP?